# acquire class name from file path

Tags: c#, class, path

I have a system that reads through a folder and saves the paths to an array list. this folder contains a bunch of class files ".cs" all of these classes implement an interface called BaseScript.

I am attempting to find the class name so that I can call class methods but you are supposed to be able to add class files to this folder on a regular basis, so I cannot hardcode the objects to be created.

e.g. I have a file called "Manufacturing.cs":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LLS
{
    class Manufacturing : BaseScript
    {
        public void init()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Manufacturing...");
        }
        public void uninit() { }
        public void recomp() { }
    }
}
```

It implements "BaseScript":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LLS
{
    public interface BaseScript
    {
        void init();
        void uninit();
        void recomp();
    }
}
```

I need to be able to use the path: "\Scripts\Manufacturing.cs" to call something like

```
BaseScript[] s = {new "Manufacturing class name"}
```

I know there must be some roundabout way of doing this. 
how can I find the class name and then create an instance from that class?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want to dynamically compile these CS files, determine if they inherit/derive from a specific class/interface, and if so instantiate them and call a method?  I'd also recommend writing at least a single sentence that is a question (typically involves using a question mark? :)

Comment: This is very confusing, do you want to be able to read the class name and then create an instance of it? Or literally just want a string with the class name (based off the line `BaseScript[] s = {new "Manufacturing class name"}`)

Comment: I'm willing to bet there is a method to what your looking for, however I would be willing to bet a lot more money that by posing a specific question you can get a specific and helpful answer.

Comment: Sorry, question was updated and tnw hits it spot on. I need to find the class name then create an instance of that class.

Edit: Sorry about the poor question, I should know better by now..

Comment: @MattHirdler Still unclear, why do you want to get the class name from *source files*? Do you want to compile them as Eric asked?

Comment: Yes I would like them compiled. There was an answer posted that looked spot on but then was deleted..

Answer (score 0):

Edit-I mistakenly though you had dlls and not cs files for some reason.

As others say you are not properly explaining the scenario. But from what I understand you are probably implementing a plugin type of pattern here. 
In order to call methods on C# classes you may add later on, you need to iterate through the folder, get the *.cs files, compile them and then using reflection, load the assembly and create an instance of a class you know exists(you should know the fully qualified name of the class beforehand). Finally, you should find the method you want to call and then call it using reflection. Here is some code to get you started:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider provider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
//You should add all referenced assembiles needed for the cs file here
//parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add();

var files = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("Scripts").GetFiles("*.cs");
foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in files)
{
    System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults result = 
        provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, new[] { System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file.FullName) });
    object instance = result.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(file.Name);
    if (instance is BaseScript)
    {
        //Do processing on (BaseScript)instance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class is in the same assembly then you can create an instance of the object by using [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I didn't try your code on my side. So casting might not work. Double check this code:

```
BaseScript s = (BaseScipt)Activator.CreateInstance(null, "Namespace.TestClass");
```